# AngularJS + MongoLab JSON response not displaying in view

Tags: mongodb, angularjs

I've written a basic angularJS + mongoLab app. The code to fetch the data works fine and in the Chrome Developer Tools I can see the response as:

```
[ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5166c406e4b08774fa6844a9"} , "tag" : "Software Developer"} , { "_id" : { "$oid" : "51679cbde4b05c7db8d21e70"} , "tag" : "Project Management"} ]
```

In my view I have:

```
<ul>
                <li ng-repeat="tagz in tags">
                    {{tagz.tag}}
                </li>
            </ul>
```

But when I display on the browser all I see is

dots but the tag values are not displayed.
My controller has:

```
'use strict';
// Define our root-level controller for the application.
        Riadd.controller(
            "AppController",
            function( $scope, $route, $routeParams, Tags){




                // Update the rendering of the page.
                var render = function(){
                    $scope.tags = Tags;

                    // Pull the "action" value out of the
                    // currently selected route.
                    var renderAction = $route.current.action;

                    // Also, let's update the render path so that
                    // we can start conditionally rendering parts
                    // of the page.
                    var renderPath = renderAction.split( "." );

                    // Grab the username out of the params.
                    //
                    // NOTE: This will be undefined for every route
                    // except for the "contact" route; for the sake
                    // of simplicity, I am not exerting any finer
                    // logic around it.
                    var username = ($routeParams.username || "");

                    // Reset the booleans used to set the class
                    // for the navigation.
                    var isHome = (renderPath[ 0 ] == "home");
                    var isFriends = (renderPath[ 0 ] == "friends");
                    var isContact = (renderPath[ 0 ] == "contact");

                    // Store the values in the model.
                    $scope.renderAction = renderAction;
                    $scope.renderPath = renderPath;
                    $scope.username = username;
                    $scope.isHome = isHome;
                    $scope.isFriends = isFriends;
                    $scope.isContact = isContact;

                };

                // Listen for changes to the Route. When the route
                // changes, let's set the renderAction model value so
                // that it can render in the Strong element.
                $scope.$on(
                    "$routeChangeSuccess",
                    function( $currentRoute, $previousRoute ){

                        // Update the rendering.
                        render();

                    }
                );

            }
        );
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Could you show us your $resource service code?  I would start with inspecting the output of `query()`.

Comment: I'm using mongolabResourceHttp.js to access the DB

Comment: What does definition 'Tag' service look like?  Does it use asynchronous data retrieval?  Then you may need to make sure to notify angular scope that data is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/angularjs-mongolab-promise/blob/master/README.md

IMHO  instead of

```
$scope.tags = Tags;
```

you will need

```
Tags.all(function(tags){
  $scope.tags = tags;
});
```